# What is the most efficient way to compare a string to Enums?

Tags: python, django, string, enums

I have the following Enum class:

```
class LabelEnum(str, Enum):
    ENUM_ONE = "Enum One"
    ENUM_TWO = "Enum Two"
    ENUM_THREE = "Enum Three"
    FOUR = "FOUR"
    FIVE = "FIVE"
    SIX = "SIX"
```

I want to compare a string with all of the members of this enum and see if the string exists in the enum class or not. I can do this by following snippet:

```
if string in LabelEnum.__members__:
    pass
```

But I want to compare the lower case of the string (`string.lower()`) with the **lower case of the enum members**. I can't do this in the above way I think. Another way is to loop through the members but that will slow the execution and I don't want that. Is there any way I can compare the lowercase of these in a single line and more efficiently than looping?

Comment: looping over the members (only 6 items) isn't going to *slow* down your program.

Comment: Six items are just for presentation purpose. There might be much more members and this needs to be done many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a "LabelEnumLower" list containing the members of LabelEnum converted to lower:

```
LabelEnumLower = [s.lower() for s in LabelEnum.__members__]
```

Now you can do `if string in LabelEnumLower:`.

Comment: I'd suggest a `set` comprehension (`{s.lower() for s in LabelEnum.__members__}`) over a `list` comp, to keep the lookup cost (mostly) fixed regardless of how many members you have.

Comment: I am adding a class method named "lower()" in the enum class using this snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Under your explanation of

> Six [enum] items are just for presentation purpose. There might be much more members and this needs to be done many times.

You should setup a comparer dictionary once and use a O(1) lookup. You could do it without but you then occure the costs of building the mapper object again and again:

```
from enum import Enum

class LabelEnum(str, Enum):
    ENUM_ONE = "Enum One"
    ENUM_TWO = "Enum Two"
    ENUM_THREE = "Enum Three"
    FOUR = "FOUR"
    FIVE = "FIVE"
    SIX = "SIX"

class EnumComparer:
    cmp = {}

    @classmethod
    def add_enum_values(cls, a_enum_type):
    """Call once with each enum you want to handle/check/convert."""
        cmp = EnumComparer.cmp
        if not issubclass(a_enum_type, Enum):
            raise ValueError(f"Not a enum: {a_enum_type}")

        # autoconvert values to string
        for name, enu in a_enum_type.__members__.items():
            # including enum class name
            key = name.lower()
            if key in cmp:
                raise ValueError(f"Duplicate for {key}({a_enum_type}): {cmp[key]}]")
            cmp[key] = enu

    @classmethod
    def parse_enum(cls, value): 
        """Returns the correct enum value or None"""
        return EnumComparer.cmp.get( str(value).lower(), None )

    @classmethod
    def is_enum(cls, value): 
        """Returns True if it is a known value"""
        return value in EnumComparer.cmp
```

**Test:**

```
EnumComparer.add_enum_values(LabelEnum)

 # a simple check would be 
 if EnumComparer.is_enum("tata"):
     # do something - but you could also simply get the correct
     # enum value from the EnumComparer
     pass

# our you get the actual enums value / None
values = ["enum_one", "EnUm_Two", "ENUM_Three", "FouR", "fIVe", "six", "Nooop"]

for what in values:
    print(what, " ==> ",EnumComparer.parse_enum(what))
```

**Output:**

```
enum_one  ==>  LabelEnum.ENUM_ONE
EnUm_Two  ==>  LabelEnum.ENUM_TWO
ENUM_Three  ==>  LabelEnum.ENUM_THREE
FouR  ==>  LabelEnum.FOUR
fIVe  ==>  LabelEnum.FIVE
six  ==>  LabelEnum.SIX
Nooop  ==>  None
```